# Using Prepared Statements with sql

Tags: php, mysql

How to use prepared statements in phpmyadmin? I have got an sql query, but when I run this, it just shows a message like my query has been successfully executed. I couldn't see the results. Please help.

my sql query is

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when exam = ''',
      exam,
      ''' then student end) AS `',
      exam, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from yourtable;

SET @sql 
    = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
              from yourtable
              group by id;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: You need to use `echo` or `print` in order to "see" results.

Comment: I used echo and print option,i couldn see the result.When i execute this query in phpmyadmin,it just shows that query is executed successfully.Couldn find any other messages other than this.

Comment: @user2743855 Try to fetch the column after EXECUTE, I'm using the same basis and it works fine for me.